# Changing layout on rotation with multiple views moving

Tags: ios, swift, ipad

I'm working on an app where I've got a design with two similar layouts for horizontal/vertical. And it's on an iPad. I've found other answers but I can't use most of them because I've got two tableviews in my view, which means I can't use xibs. I'm also making it for the iPad so changing layout based on height/width variation doesn't work.

The design I'm trying to achieve is in the pictures below. What I'm having troubles with is moving the two views that are stacked on the right in landscape mode to be next to each other and short in vertial. Also I need to move those four buttons and the right-side table to being below the other two views.

[image: iPad design prototypes]

I've tried overriding trait functions as described in [this blog post](https://blogs.perficient.com/2017/09/22/how-to-handle-ipad-landscape-and-portrait-layout-using-size-class/) but for the life of me can not get it to work.

I'm looking for any advice anyone could give me. I feel like I've hit a wall and can not figure out how I can implement this.

Answer (score 0):

just give the height and width constraints of the subviews with respect to the superview in ratio it'll work.